# Sorting records from multiple excel workbooks - C# Excel Interop

Tags: c#, excel, sorting, excel-interop

I have a c# applicaion that rights event results into workbooks and worksheets.  The windows form in which the event results are entered contains a textbox for each particular result field (ie. name, score, time, competitor #, etc.) and there are about 19 rows of these textboxes that the user can enter the results in.  Many of these textbox fields are auto-filled after the user registered the competitors for the event such as name, competitor #, address, etc.  My main issue is that there are several races being run under three different categories and I need my application to somehow find the best overal score/time from every event for each category.  Currently I am out putting the values from the textbox fields on the registration form to an excel spreadsheet using the excel interop and arraylists within for loops.  I am then sorting the values in the Excel spreadsheet by using the range.sort method.  I am having trouble conceptually devising a way in which I can perform what I am trying to accomplish as the events will be on different worksheets.  Does anyone have any suggestions on a course of action I should look into.  I know this is more of a conceptual question on the excel interop, but I really couldn't include code for this as there is way too much involved.  Thanks for any help.

Comment: I think you might need to give an approximate schematic of how your data is organised. I'm not sure I see the problem with sorting each spreadsheet separately since they will all be sorted the same way and so in the same order. You can have more than one workbook open at once, if that's what you require.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

... I wouldn't do this with Excel.
I'd rather do this via a custom object that can hold all the data you need. For Example:

```
Public Class EventData

Public Property CompetitorName As String
' ... Other Info you've inputted

Public Property EventName As String = ""
Public Property Category As String = ""

Public Property Score As Double = -1
Public Property Time As Double = -1

Public ReadOnly Property ComparisonVal As Double
    Get
        ' This could be either Score or Time
        ' Decide based upon which one <> -1 or something along those lines
    End Get
End Property

End Class
```

Now you could, in your code, do something like:

```
Dim AllData as New List(Of EventData)
```

And populate the list with all your necessary data (just as you did the excel sheets)

Now, you can pull the data however you want using `LinQ` and grouping by `Event` & `Category` and taking the top 3 (or whatever) `ComparisonVal` values.

Later on, you could always output your custom object data to Excel using [Epplus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/) or Interop if you needed it stored that way, but I'd rely on .Net to do all the heavy lifting for you since there you have the greatest degree of flexibility with your code / variables, etc.

Hope this explains my idea and sorry for the VB code :)